# Real time data feed using NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, mongodb

I am identifying the face for attendance system and planning to store the info in MongoDB. I am not able to verify is it possible or not neither I am getting any close to it. Currently I am storing it in excel sheet and then transferring it into database but for real time feeding it won’t be too good of a method I guess. If anyone knows in this can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah u can. i recommande u to work with Mongoose.
Mongoose is an Object Data Modeling (ODM) library for MongoDB and Node.js. It manages relationships between data, provides schema validation, and is used to translate between objects in code and the representation of those objects in MongoDB.